# OpenId for gmail

Tags: openid

Anybody know how to get gmail's OpenID working?  All I find is this http://openid-provider.appspot.com/, which gives 302 moved followed by GET not supported on this URL.

I'm assuming this one is broken. Any others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's not possible. But the opposite (using a gmail account as a openID) i think it's possible.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it is close to what I ended up doing (I lost patience and created an OpenId from myopenid using the gmail account for reset password.

Anyway, the correct answer is subject to change.

Comment: This answer is wrong! When it asks for your openID put in the URL https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id and then google will redirect for you to login and allow the site to use your email as a openID!

Comment: @ing0 are you answering a question from 2008? In 2008 it was other thing my friend..

Comment: ing0 look the answer from TiansHUo please.

Comment: I had the same issue the other day, I didn't see the question date but the answer is still incorrect for now. The other answer should be accepted - this is the point of SO isn't it? To give up to date information? Also, I believe the intended use of google as an openID was launched around the time of this question anyway...

Comment: Or at least edit your answer to be up to date!

Comment: @VP the answer being historically correct or not is of no help to people who Google this problem.

Comment: our comments do. you are free to vote on the valid answer in 2014 and make sure that they don't get invalid in 2015 and that they were valid as well in 2013..

Answer (score 52):

Update: this no-longer works.

---

This works as an OpenID: <strike>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id</strike> (worked in 2008, 404s in 2016)

It went live on October 30th, 12 days after the question was asked.

See http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/moving-another-step-closer-to-single.html

Comment: nope, this link just download useless xml-file

Comment: @vladkras, thanks. I've fixed the link. To keep things tidy I'll delete this comment once you've deleted yours as these comments are now outdated

Answer (score 17):

Update: Some pages do not support https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id format, if they ask for an url, I found a way to do use your Google Account (gmail) as an OpenID.

1. Browse to http://www.google.com/profiles/me and sign in
2. If you don't have a profile, create one.
3. Use http://www.google.com/profiles/yournamehere as the OpenID, it should the url of the browser

Comment: Third step didn't work for me. I used http://google.com/profiles/username instead

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to use your GMail account as an OpenID? Go through Blogspot -- it's tied to your GMail account. Just create a new blog, like "myblog.blogspot.com", and then you can use that for signing in to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify:

gmail now provides an OpenID to allow gmail account holders to connect to sites that accept OpenID

as far as I know, it is not yet possible to connect to gmail/google accounts as a result of a non-gmail OpenID;

I've put in an edit of the question as it's clearer for people who discover the question as a result of searching the web, that way